# 2gis deeplink не работает под Android

Tags: android, 2gis-api

Все сделано по документации:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/"+adapter.getItem(position).gps);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

открывается приложение, но маршрут не строит! Сначала пишет подключитесь к интернету чтобы построить маршрут (хотя он есть), кликаешь попробовать еще раз и наконец интернет находится, но вот проезд не найден, попробуйте построить маршрут по-другому. Тоже самое через [https://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/координаты](https://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B)
не строит маршрут.
Документация не соответствует действительности? Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: Вы пример приведите с координатами, возможно вы путаете ширину и долготу местами, поэтому никакого маршрута и не строит.

Comment: А что у вас вот тут получается `adapter.getItem(position).gps`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev нет ничего не спутанно. Забиваю те же координаты в строку поиска на 2GIS сайте все нормально находит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб там координаты места разделенные запятой

Comment: Что я могу вас сказать, пишите в ТП 2гиса.